# Key Choice When Using Cassandra's RandomPartitioner

Tags: nosql, cassandra

When you using the OrderPreservingPartitioner with a column family key of say an int representing YYYYMMDD you'll get hotspots on write and most of the load will hit one/two of the nodes in a cassandra ring. If you are using the RandomPartitioner will cassandra spread the load when using a key that doesn't change frequently (i.e YYYYMMDD)?

In short does the RandomPartitioner spread the load on a small discrete number of key values that do not change regularly?

Is the Partirioner choice a keyspace or cluster level setting?

To Note: So if you md5 20110902 you get 59b7841383176e942495550ecc801a9e. If I repeatably load data with the key 20110902 (i.e 59b7841383176e942495550ecc801a9e) will that not just allocate data to one single node that has the 59b78413.... assigned to it. Is there something else Cassandra is doing to spread the load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the RandomPartitioner cannot spread the load if you keep reusing the same keys.  It spreads the load by assigning different keys to different nodes, but inserts on the same key will always go to the same node(s).

Cassandra does spread the load through the replication factor, so for example if you use RF=3, there are three nodes that a key could live on.  However if you keep using key 20110902, it will be the same three nodes every time.

In short load balancing happens at the key level.  To spread the load, you need to choose different keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RandomPartitioner the load will be evenly distributed. Each key will be md5ed, and the value of the md5 hash will decide where your data will be stored.

The configuration is per cluster

Comment: So if you md5 20110902 you get 59b7841383176e942495550ecc801a9e. If I repeatably load data with the key 20110902 (i.e 59b7841383176e942495550ecc801a9e) will that not just allocate data to one single node that has the 59b78413.... assigned to it. Is there something else Cassandra is doing to spread the load

Comment: Rows are partitioned by key, so One Big Row would be an antipattern.